# Elasticsearch - How can I store a little images in my documents?

Tags: image, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.5.2 and Sense to manage my documents. I want to add a little image in every document stored. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

ES isn't really a binary document store, you can do it but it won't be very efficient.It will be better if you  store the images outside of ES . Image storage typically is something better handled by a filesystem .

> How can I do it?

use of type binary will do this job ,The binary type needs to be base64 encoded and will not be indexed by default :-

```
POST http://localhost:9200/images/
{
    "mappings" : {
    "images" : {
        "properties" : {
            "image" : { "type" : "binary"},
            "id" : {"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

You can check this also  ,  `Image Plugin for Elasticsearch` , If you have intension for indexing and searching similar image than `LIRE` (Lucene Image Retrieval) is good option.

https://github.com/kzwang/elasticsearch-image